# How to import database data into combo box in javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

Using this code I Initialized Combo box

```
@FXML
private ComboBox category;
```

And get value using:

```
String Category = category.getValue().toString();
```

And inserted value to mysql database.
Now before inserting next value in category Combo box I need to import the values in the database to the drop down in Combo Box and value should be displayed in the combo box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to read the values from the database and save it into a ObservableList, once you get all the values you can fill the combobox with:

```
 combobox.setItems(myObservableList);
```

if your type of combobox is not "String" you should use a String converter, for example, if you wanna fill the combobox with the name of users, being "user" a class and name an attribute, you just have to:

```
myCombo.setConverter(new StringConverter<user>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(user object) {
                return object.getName();
            }

            @Override
            public user fromString(String string) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        });
```