# JavaFX: Populating a ComboBox with data from a MySQL Database, StringConverter breaking the combobox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fxml

I have a ComboBox, which I'd like to populate with data from a database. Using the following code, the data that is displayed in the ComboBox is the ID of the value, not the `string` value.

(Partial) Java Controller Code:

```
@FXML
    ComboBox studentPicker;
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        String dbUsername = "root";
        String dbPassword = "x";
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uia";
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            // Execute query and store result in a resultset
            ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT username FROM user WHERE userrole='STUDENT';");
            while (rs.next()) {
                //get string from db,whichever way 
                data.add(new User(rs.getString("username")));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error"+ex);
        }

        studentPicker.setItems(null);
        studentPicker.setItems(data);
    }
```

The `StringConverter` I tried was picked up from [How to import database data into combo box in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606353/how-to-import-database-data-into-combo-box-in-javafx), but this caused an error with the ComboBox. See image below: Image on the left is how it is supposed to be, right image is how it is when the StringConverter is added to the code.

[image: How it is supposed to be]
[image: How it is when adding the StringConverter below to the code]

```
studentPicker.setConverter(new StringConverter<User>() {

        @Override
        public String toString(User object) {
            return object.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public User fromString(String string) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    });
```

What I'd like to display is the usernames collected from the Database, but ID's like "is20x.User@4b6ca8f7" is displayed instead.
Any suggestion to how I can solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are adding a `new User("name")` to the `data` array. That is why you are getting `"is20x.User@4b6ca8f7"`. If your `User` class has a `getName()` or `getUsername()` method, call that instead. So something like `data.add(new User(rs.getString("username")).getUserName());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering from my comment.

You are adding a `new User("username")` to your `data` array which is why you are getting a weird String, its the ID of that particular `User`.

Try instead doing `data.add(new User(rs.getString("username")).getUserName());`, if you `User` class has a `getUserName()` method.

This may break what you are trying to do all around though, as I assume you use `data` more that just here. It might be best to make another variable and store you comboBox strings in that. So something like

```
//Init same place data is
comboString = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //Declared somewhere else
data.add(new User(rs.getString("username")));
comboString.add(rs.getString("username"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I want to share what I did to automatically set the data from MySQL database. (that is very simple)

```
        // first I execute the query that select name of department one by one
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select name from department");

        while (resultSet.next()) {  // loop

           // Now add the comboBox addAll statement 
            comboBox.getItems().addAll(resultSet.getString("name")); 
       }
```

note here the "name" field  in last line, is exactly spelled same as the name of the column in MySQL table.